# AngularJS ngTable doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, web-services, factory, ngtable

I already used ngTable with static data before, it worked well (listing, sorting and filtering). I'm using ngTable v 0.8.3

**My Goal**

This time I want to create a ngTable with data loaded from a Web Service.
I made a custom factory to be able to create my ngTable with future others entities.

**Issue**

It doesn't work and I have no JS console errors. When I debug, I can clearly see that my method query from my service Employee return me my complete and correct objet containing employees details. I enter in the getData() function, the ngTable is being created, but with empty data.

**Relevant and lightweighten code**

Here is my HTML markup :

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped" show-filter="true">
      <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="employee in $data">      
   <td data-title="'employee.firstname' | translate" filter="{'firstname' : 'text'}" sortable="'firstname'"><a ui-sref="employee.detail({id:employee.id})">{{employee.firstname}}</a></td>
   <td data-title="'employee.lastname' | translate" filter="{lastname : 'text'}" sortable="'lastname'">{{employee.lastname}}</td>
   <td data-title="'employee.mail' | translate" filter="{mail : 'text'}" sortable="'mail'">{{employee.mail}}</td>
   <td data-title="'employee.phone-number' | translate" filter="{phone_number : 'text'}" sortable="'phone_number'">{{employee.phone_number}}</td>
   <td data-title="'employee.birthdate' | translate" filter="{birthdate : 'text'}" sortable="'birthdate'">{{employee.birthdate}}</td>      
           </tr>
      </tbody></table>
```

my Angular controller :

```
myapp.controller('EmployeeController', function ($rootScope, $scope, Employee, ngTableParams, ngTableFactory) {
       $scope.tableParams = ngTableFactory.create(20, {lastname: 'asc'});   // count, sorting
});
```

And my Angular factory :

```
myapp.factory('ngTableFactory', function(ngTableParams, Employee) {
    return {
        create: function(count, sorting) {
            return new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // initial page
                count: count,       // count per page
                sorting: sorting    // initial sorting
            }, {
                total: 0,
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    Employee.query({page: params.page(), size: params.count()}, function(result) {
                        $defer.resolve(result);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Edit 1, progresses :

My items are being listed if I remove params from my query method, so it was a bad handling of my Employee service. But, the sort and filter does not work on my table by default. to make sorting works, I have to add this line on my ngTable factory, in the getData() function :

```
result = $filter('orderBy')(result, params.orderBy());
```

Normally, the sorting of basic elements works as I added the 'sortable' keyword in my HTML ngtable template columns, and as I'm fetching my data over $data item. Still investigating.

Thanks for your help mates !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your code works.

Please see https://github.com/masa67/NgTable for a working example (based on Node). I did not change anything (except filled-in the missing parts, maybe the problem is there).

The table formatting is not correct, but at least the data is coming in.

Comment: thank you for your implication! when you say the table formatting is not correct, what are you talking about ?
from the view,I managed to try quotes wrapping, data or $data as object to fetch, to modify ng-table name etc ... My table is create, because my filter input area and sort mechanisms are created at page load. but data is not coming in

Comment: The formatting problem is probably only in my example code. I can have a look at it later, if needed. The key is that your code was working for me, so the problem must be somewhere else than in the code in your problem description above.

Comment: I removed some params I was sending through my Employee query method and the content is being correctly listed. However, I can't sort or filter. And I need these params to paginate server side so it's not a solution. I 'll keep diging.

Comment: I'm back along this subject. is it possible that my ngTable is recreated at each filter/sort with the initial values ? But it shouldn't work on your example then ... mhh

Comment: Sorting and filtering is the problem in my example as well. Sorry, I could not figure it out, why it is not working.